# Why should we use twitter api insted of getting it from the non-api URL?

Tags: api, url, twitter

I was wondering if i can use the PHP library of Brandom 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/Twitter.class.php.txt

Instead of using the twitter API which has rate limit.

What about using this:
http:// twitter.com/users/show/'.$id.".$format";

Instead of this:
https:// api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/'.$id.".$format";

The 2nd one uses the API. The first one...i guess it doesn't.
So... can i use the fist one for this same purpose?

THanks.

Comment: :) Almost correct, you can upvote comments as well. If you collect upvote count 5 or more enough number of times you can get awarded. There is another limit at 10 votes, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reasons you might want to use Twitter API:**

- Well documented and easy to comprehend
- Proper explanation for the caught exception
- Most reliable and real time results
- Many dimensions to extract the data
- Active community that resolves the issues(bugs, confusions ..etc). Also as the developers are Twitter guys, nothing could be more reliable as they know their product better.
- Last but not the least, very easy to use

As far as "**Rate Limit**" is concerned, it can be dealt using **Streaming API**.

Comment: So, what i was talking about was about the streaming API?

Comment: If your primary problem is rate limit, then yes!

Comment: So, is this from the Streaming API?  http:// twitter.com/users/show/USERID.json  or not.

Comment: No, a streaming API example would be something like this: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json

Comment: So, what is that then? It allows us to look for users info too. Is that rate limited? How can i get the same data with the stream API that with this url: http:// twitter.com/users/show/USERID.json

Comment: Yes, it would allow you to extract much more than what you could do with url: http:// twitter.com/users/show/USERID.json . And it is not rate limited. Visit "stackoverflow.com/questions/8431064/simple-twitter-streaming-api-script/8455221#8455221" and try to comprehend with the link I have provided. Do upvote that answer if it helps :).